# angular directive map object that has function inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to create a directive that has an argument which is an object.
This object has a property `map` that can be a function.

Every time I run it I get this error

> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=159&p3=%5B%7B%20name%20:%20%27Nom%27,%20map%20:%20%27id%27%20%7D,%7B%20name%20:%20%27Description%27,%20map%20:%20%27titre_fr%27%20%7D,%7B%20name%20:%20%27Type%20de%20Valeur%27,%20map%20:%20%27type_valeur%27%20%7D,%20%7B%20name%20:%20%27test%27,%20map%20:%20function(d)%20%7B%20return%20%27ok%27;%20%7D%7D%5D&p4=%7B%20return%20%27ok%27;%20%7D%7D%5D

My directive is defined like this :

**directive.js**

```
.directive('apiTable', ['$rootScope', 'APIService', function($rootScope, APIService)
{
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : '/js/angular/app/ui/api-table.html',
        transclude : true,
        scope :
        {
            mapping : '=',
            route : '@'
        },
        controller : function($scope)
        {
            $scope.data = [];
            $scope.page = 0;
            this.mapResult = function(data)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    var temp = [];
                    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.mapping.length; j++)
                    {
                        temp[0] = i + 1;
                        if(typeof(data[i][$scope.mapping[j].map]) !== 'undefined')
                        {
                            if(typeof(data[i][$scope.mapping[j].map]) == 'function')
                            {
                                console.log('ok')
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                temp[j + 1] = data[i][$scope.mapping[j].map];
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp[j + 1] = "";
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.data.push(temp);
                }
            };
            this.getData = function(p)
            {
                APIService.getData($scope.route, p)
                    .then(function(data)
                    {
                        this.mapResult(data.results);
                    }.bind(this));
            };
            this.getData({ p : $scope.page });
        }
    };
}])
```

And the call is like this :

**view.html**

```
<api-table route="_dictionnaryAPIFindByDomain" mapping="[{ name : 'Nom', map : 'id' },{ name : 'Description', map : 'titre_fr' },{ name : 'Type de Valeur', map : 'type_valeur' }, { name : 'test', map : function(d) { return 'ok'; }}]"></api-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> No Function Declarations: You cannot declare functions in an Angular expression, even inside ng-init directive.
>   [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

It looks like that rule also applies to object properties

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  {{ {a:'b',c:function(){}} }}
</div>
```

Easiest fix is to encode it to JSON and then parse it.

Comment: This is not that simple. My mapping is made in the html file. To stringify it with json I have to use JS.

Comment: Could you post in your question how mapping is being made/set? It seems odd to construct functions in your html.